# Missing proxy classes when container compiles custom ExtensionPass

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony-services

## Context

I try to find a way to integrate Webpack Encore into Drupal. Since we can't use Symfony Bundles in Drupal I want to port the bundle to a custom Drupal module.

## What I have done so far

To register an alter services I use a custom compiler pass described [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic#s-how-to-create-a-custom-compiler-pass)

So my Service Provider looks like that:

```
class WebpackEncoreServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function register(ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new WebpackEncoreExtensionPass());
    }
}
```

My custom extension pass looks like that:

```
class WebpackEncoreExtensionPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        //get the parameters from mymodule.services.yml
        $configs = Yaml::parseFile(\dirname(__DIR__).'/../webpack_encore.services.yml');
        $config = $configs['parameters']['webpack_encore'];
        // Drupal does not load configs from files like Symfony does.
        $container->prependExtensionConfig('webpack_encore', ['output_path' => $config['output_path']]);
        $extension = new WebpackEncoreExtension();
        $extension->load([$config], $container);
        $container->registerExtension($extension);
        $container->loadFromExtension($extension->getAlias());
//      var_dump($container->getDefinitions());die();
        $container->compile();
    }
}
```

## Problem

The container is not build a states that there are missing proxy classes. This output is from the browser and it runs in circles:

```
User warning: Missing proxy class 'Symfony\Component\ProxyClass\HttpKernel\HttpKernel' for lazy service 'http_kernel.basic'. Use the following command to generate the proxy class: php core/scripts/generate-proxy-class.php 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel' "[namespace_root_path]" in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ProxyServicesPass->process() (line 61 of /var/www/html/mws_bundles/dietpet.vet/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ProxyServicesPass.php).
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ProxyServicesPass->process(Object) (Line: 94)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object) (Line: 762)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() (Line: 34)
Drupal\webpack_encore\Compiler\WebpackEncoreExtensionPass->process(Object) (Line: 94)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object) (Line: 762)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() (Line: 1293)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->compileContainer() (Line: 898)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 471)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 705)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
User warning: Missing proxy class 'Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle' for lazy service 'http_middleware.kernel_pre_handle'. Use the following command to generate the proxy class: php core/scripts/generate-proxy-class.php 'Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle' "core/lib/Drupal/Core" in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ProxyServicesPass->process() (line 61 of /var/www/html/mws_bundles/dietpet.vet/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ProxyServicesPass.php).
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ProxyServicesPass->process(Object) (Line: 94)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object) (Line: 762)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() (Line: 34)
Drupal\webpack_encore\Compiler\WebpackEncoreExtensionPass->process(Object) (Line: 94)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object) (Line: 762)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() (Line: 1293)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->compileContainer() (Line: 898)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 471)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 705)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
User warning: Missing proxy class 'Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\StackMiddleware\Session' for lazy service 'http_middleware.session'. Use the following command to generate the proxy class: php core/scripts/generate-proxy-class.php 'Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session' "core/lib/Drupal/Core" in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ProxyServicesPass->process() (line 61 of /var/www/html/mws_bundles/dietpet.vet/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ProxyServicesPass.php).
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ProxyServicesPass->process(Object) (Line: 94)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object) (Line: 762)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() (Line: 34)
Drupal\webpack_encore\Compiler\WebpackEncoreExtensionPass->process(Object) (Line: 94)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object) (Line: 762)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() (Line: 1293)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->compileContainer() (Line: 898)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 471)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 705)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

I tried the commands mentioned on the console but this also runs in circles and does not generate the proxy classes.

What I wonder is this command:

```
php core/scripts/generate-proxy-class.php 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel' "[namespace_root_path]"
```

Shouldn't there be a real path?

How can I solve this problem?

Should this be considered a bug? If yes where can I file a bug report?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had to remove `$container->compile();` cause this is done by drupal in a later step.